# Getting the name of the node and its corresponding values in xml using linq to xml in c#?

Tags: c#, xml, linq-to-xml

I want to get the name of the node and its corresponding values in a xml file using linq to xml.

I usually do this line of code to get the value of the node and store it in a list

```
var qry = from c in XElement.Load(commonpath).Elements("Root") select c;

        List<string> result = new List<string>();
        foreach (var i in qry)
        {
            result.Add(Convert.ToString(i));
        }
```

But now I want both node name and value to store it in a dictionary

```
Dictionary<string, double> amount = new Dictionary<string, double>();
        var qry = "";//what query here
        foreach(var i in qry)
        {
            amount.Add("Node Name", "Value");
        }
```

So what is the right query for this situation please help. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope this is what you are looking for:

```
    var doc = XDocument.Parse(@"
         <root>
            <firstname>Lucas</firstname>
            <lastname>Ontivero</lastname>
         </root>");
    var qry = from element in doc.Element("root").Descendants() select element;
    var result = qry.ToDictionary(e => e.Name, e => e.Value);
    result.ToList().ForEach(x=> Console.WriteLine("{0}:{1}", x.Key, x.Value ));
```

It prints:

```
  firstname:Lucas
  lastname:Ontivero
```

Let me know if it is useful.
Good luck!

Comment: I´m sure you already know you cannot have two elements with the same name, right? Because dictionaries cannot to have duplicated keys. Be careful with that.